# Sending image + text email using smtplib in python

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send an email with images to an email address, but I do not know the codes to sent picture emails in this example, can anyone help me out! thank you

using `from email.mime.image import MIMEImage` doesn't seem to work too on this

> Some background information: it's a fitness training program that extracts user email and name to sent it, therefore the `def email_user(email, name):`

```
import smtplib

def email_user(email, name):

fromaddr = 'something@gmail.com'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login('something@gmail.com', '1234567890')

image = "/Users/Desktop/imagehere.jpeg"

greeting = "\n<p style=\"font-size:30px; text-align: center; color:Red;\"> <b>Amazing Workout " + name + "! </b> </p> <br>"
performance_summary = "\n<p style=\"font-size:20px; text-align: center;\"><b>Here is your Performance Summary<b> for "

message = greeting + performance_summary

server.sendmail(fromaddr, email, message)


def main():
    # Test Emailing
    email_user("email", "name")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [send html email with embedded image using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186048/send-html-email-with-embedded-image-using-python-script)

Comment: hi i tried but cant seem to make it work !

Comment: can you show the code where you actually try to read and include the image in your email-body?

Comment: @mnikley i dont have that part of the code... idk how to do it

Comment: You have an example in the link i provided..

Comment: @mnikley it dosnt seem to work ...